# Can we handle voice command from assistant widget?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, app-actions

I'm able to integrate Android widgets with `Google Assistant`. And want to have some voice command experience.

For example the `CREATE_CALL` intent, if user is trying to call Alice by saying `call Alice with some app`, and if there are 2 Alice in my app, is it possible for me to response with a widget showing 2 Alice, and asking user by voice, and user can choose which one to actually call, all by voice? Can it be done by [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly speaking, App Actions do not have a voice conversation experience. There are some tricks you can pull that might head in that direction, but they are largely outside of the App Action Widget experience itself.

**Can I respond with a widget showing that there are multiple matches?**

Yes, you can send back a Control Widget that might allow them to choose which user they mean.

**Can they speak which user?**

Probably not in the way you're thinking. To use your example, they can re-invoke the `CREATE_CALL` BII using any of the phrases, but you can't prompt them with "Who did you mean, exactly?" and for them to just say the name.

**Can I use the `SpeechRecognizer` API?**

Not as part of a widget.

Widgets get embedded in the conversation with the Assistant.

In theory (and this is on my list to eventually test and figure out), you should be able to deep link to an Android Intent in cases such as this and open a view. While there, you could use `SpeechRecognizer` or just open the microphone to send audio somewhere. But this isn't done using the Widget itself.

In this scenario, `SpeechRecognizer` just does the Speech To Text (STT) or Automatic Speech Recognition (ASR) part of the processing. To actually match this up to phrases to determine an Intent, you would need a Natural Language Understanding (NLU) module such as Dialogflow. (But you may not need the `SpeechRecognizer` in that particular case, since Dialogflow can also take an audio stream to do the ASR part for you.)

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner. So even we are trying to use SpeechRecognizer API. We can only get the recording, and we need to extract the intent by ourselves. Is that correct?

Comment: Sort of. SpeechRecognizer would do speech-to-text (STT) (what is sometimes called ASR - Automatic Speech Recognition), so you would get the text spoken, but it does not match that to an Intent. To do that, you need an NLU (Natural Language Understanding) module which would either take that text and match it to phrases or take an audio stream/recording and do the same - something like Dialogflow.

Comment: If an answer has helped - accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.